# Hibernate One to Many Mapping returns null

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to create a one to many relationship. 1 smsConfig can have many params.

My SmsConfig entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sms_config")
@Getter
@Setter
public class SmsConfig {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy  = "smsConfig")
   private List <Param> param = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Params:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "param")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Param {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sms_config_id")
    private SmsConfig smsConfig;

}
```

But when I query the SmsConfig table, the param arraylist is null in the smsConfig object. This is how I query:

```
SmsConfig smsConfig = smsConfigRepository.findOne(id);
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you accessing the Param object explicitly? Otherwise you will probably need EAGER fetching on that entity.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Comment: I have added "fetch = FetchType.EAGER" to the param array list, but when I run findOne(id), it does a circular fetch. ie: param has smsConfig and smsConfig has param and so on.